# Custom Error Message while implementing IValidatableObject

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

I have implemented `IValidatableObject` with no issues:

```
 public class DisclaimerCBs : IValidatableObject
 {
        public bool cb1 { get; set; } = false;
        public bool cb2 { get; set; } = false;
        public bool cb3 { get; set; } = false;

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            Type type = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
            IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> checkBoxeProperties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(bool));

            bool allIsChecked = true;
            foreach (PropertyInfo checkBoxProperty in checkBoxeProperties)
            {
                var isChecked = (bool)checkBoxProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);
                if (!isChecked)
                {
                    allIsChecked = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!allIsChecked)
                yield return new ValidationResult("Please agree to all Disclaimers. ");

            //TRUE IF THIS FAR
            yield return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
}
```

However, this only presents the error message in the Validation Summary. I would like to also have this error bring focus to a specified `<div>` element AND reiterate the error in a label much like property validators do using `<span asp-validation-for="Model.Property"></span>` . How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `Validate` method with the following:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
     Type type = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
     IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> checkBoxeProperties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(bool));

     List<ValidationResult> validationResult = new List<ValidationResult>();

     foreach (PropertyInfo checkBoxProperty in checkBoxeProperties)
     {
         var isChecked = (bool)checkBoxProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);
         if (!isChecked)
         {
             validationResult.Add(new ValidationResult("Please agree to this Disclaimer.", new[] { checkBoxProperty.Name }));
         }
     }

     return validationResult;
}
```

Comment: How would I call reference your example with the TagHelper?  `<span asp-validation-for=""></span>`  Thanks @TanvirArjel

Comment: I have updated the answer. It will automatically reference to the tag helper if your tag helpers' names  are as same as the properties name of the DisclaimerCBs model class.  Please check it.